# Spring Data Rest @EmbeddedId converters registration

Tags: spring, rest

I have spring data rest project with EmbeddedId that I have created a converter for. My configuration is in XML and I have registered the converter like this:

```
<bean id="conversionService"
 class="org.springframework.context.support.ConversionServiceFactoryBean">
    <property name="converters">
        <set>
            <bean class="example.MyCustomConverter"/>
       </set>
    </property>
</bean>
```

For some reason I am still get the no converter found error, not sure what I am missing here.

Found a solution for this problem:

It seems like I don't even need a converter here. Just having a `toString()` and constructor with a single string argument (that can parse the `toString()` output) in the ID class is sufficient here.

Comment: include the entity class with the EmbeddedId and MyCustomConverter here

Comment: it seems like I don't even need a converter here. Just having a toString() and constructor with a single string argument (that can parse the toString() output) in the ID class is sufficient here.

Comment: Write that as the answer to your question, it helped me, and I almost missed it since you wrote it as a comment.

Comment: this solution made my day was stuck with it for a day thanks

Comment: Your solution didn't work for me, no ID is used at all! "self": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/siteStats"
          } very frustrating :( My composite key uses joda time inside, may be it's one reason